# logging issue while using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, logging, jdbc

I'm using jdbc for the first time and reading from a file which contains sql queries I wrote earlier. Although the queries are properly executed and my program goes on without any apparent issue, After I've `statement.executeBatch();`, I cannot write anything into my log anymore.

-I'm using the `java.util.logging` to do my logging with a `FileHandler`. To read my ".sql" file, I'm using a `BufferedReader` and a `FileReader`. I know I'm not sharing a lot of code to fully understand the context, but that's all I have from memory. I'm closing all the readers after use.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

```
MyLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "it does write");
statement.executeBatch();
MyLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "it doesn't write anymore");
statement.close();
MyLogger.log(Level.WARNING, "still doesn't");
```

Thanks

**edit:** MyLogger is a class with a statig log method

**edit2:** @Tim Biegeleisen
`statement.executeBatch()` returns an array of int, one for each batch. I tried :

```
try {
            int[] results = statement.executeBatch();
            for (int result : results)
            {
                if (result == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) 
                {
                    MyLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "batch failed, but driver seems to still be alive.");
                    System.out.println("batch failed, but driver seems to still be alive.");
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            MyLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "the batch failed, and the driver died too.");
            System.out.println("the batch failed, and the driver died too.");
        }
```

and it printed and logged nothing.

**edit3:** I guess I was asking too much of my shutdown hook. I'm not familiar with it so I'm not sure what was precisely the problem.

Comment: What is MyLogger? Is it a (badly named) instance of a logger or is it a class containing a static log method? If it is a class then you really need to post the code for that class at least.

Comment: ... and your logging configuration.

Comment: I gave you an answer more which is somewhat speculative, but it will at least let you rule out some possible explanations.

Comment: MyLogger is indeed a class with a statig log method, a pretty standard one I suppose. I'll add more code tomorrow when I'll be at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation which seems most likely to me is that your code is rolling over upon hitting `executeBatch()`.  After this, the subsequent calls to the logger do not appear to be working, because they aren't being hit at all.  One simple way to test this would be to surround your call to `executeBatch()` with a try catch block:

```
try {
    int result = statement.executeBatch();
    if (result == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
        MyLogger.log(Level.ERROR, "batch failed, but driver seems to still be alive.");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    MyLogger.log(Level.ERROR, "the batch failed, and the driver died too.");
}
```

Comment: The thing is, it's just myLogger that is not writing to my log file. All the rest of the code is working fine, I've used alerts before and after the broken MyLogger.log('bla') and they're popping up just fine.

Comment: In any case, please implement this code when you get a chance.  Even if there be no exception, you might be getting an `EXECUTE_FAILED` response, which could explain the logger dying.  I would assume that _something_ is happening on this line of code.  I'll delete this once we can rule it out.

Comment: Sure, I will first thing in the morning.

Comment: @RBayo Maybe you could add a brief comment here about what was actually happening.

Comment: I think the problem was me, not understanding shutdown hooks. I mean I still fully don't but I now assume I'm not meant to do heavy tasks within it

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I was asking too much of my shutdown hook. I'm not familiar with it >so I'm not sure what was precisely the problem.

See: [LogManager$Cleaner() can prevent logging in other shutdown hooks](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161253).
If you are trying to perform logging in a shutdown hook then you are racing with the LogManager$Cleaner thread.

As a workaround to creating a custom shutdown hook you can create a custom handler and install it on the root logger.
The first action of the LogManager$Cleaner is to close all the installed handlers on the logger.
Once the cleaner calls the close on the custom handler you can then do one of the following:

1. Have LogManager$Cleaner run your shutdown code inside the handler.
2. Find your custom shutdown hook using the [Thread API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#enumerate-java.lang.Thread:A-) and [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) with it which will block the cleaner thread.

Comment: Thanks for the info; that might be valuable in the future.